# Heroku push: must we commit runtime.txt

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

Is runtime.txt supposed to be git commited before deploying to Heroku?

I currently have a runtime.txt correctly filled up (python-3.8.6), but it seems ignored when I run `git push heroku master`:

```
$ git push heroku master -v
Pushing to https://git.heroku.com/my-app-xxxx.git
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 890 bytes | 890.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
POST git-receive-pack (1059 bytes)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.7.5) is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 2bb6cb469f45a6165948a97c6ef8exxxxx
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 2bb6cb469f45a6165948a97c6ef8exxxxx
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
[...]
```

Although:

```
$ cat runtime.txt 
python-3.8.6
```

And for info:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
 (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .vscode/
    __pycache__/my-app-xxxx.cpython-38.pyc
    runtime.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Response: yes, runtime.txt is not processed at the Heroku CLI level apparently, but on the server side, so it has to be committed to be taken into account.